# Exact positive integer from array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print out all positive number in array and exclude negative number.
For example, I have {0,-3,5,6,-9}. The result I want is [0,5,6]. But What I have so far is it prints only positive number and store 0 for negative number ([0,0,5,6,0]).

Here is what I have right now:

```
public int[] extractPositives(int[] intArray) {
    int[] array = new int[intArray.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            if (intArray[i] >= 0)
                array[i] = intArray[i];
     }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `0` is not positive (and neither negative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested to do it only using array, you can try :

```
public int[] extractPositives(int[] intArray) {

   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
         if (intArray[i] >= 0)
           count++;
    }

   if(count == 0){
               return null;
   }

   int[] array = new int[count];
   count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
         if (intArray[i] >= 0)
            array[count++] = intArray[i];
   }
return array;
```

}

But that's certainly an ugly solution. Try ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`filter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) in [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8):

```
Integer[] result = Arrays.asList(0, -3, 5, 6, -9).stream().filter(e -> e >= 0).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: IMO, in terms of readability, this is the absolute best method. This sort of thing is what makes Java 8 so much fun.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use only two arrays you could use a linkedlist to append your result and then use the toArray method on it to have back an array with the results ...

```
public int[] extractPositives(int[] intArray) {
    List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<Integer>();
     for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            if (intArray[i] >= 0)
                res.add(intArray[i]);
     }
    return res.toArray(new int[0]);
}
```

Comment: +1 Use an ArrayList and avoid arrays if possible. Convert the List to an array if (for some reason) you have to use (yukky) arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an ArrayList if you want to store your results first:

Create one at the beginning:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

and store the value in this list instead of your new array:

```
myList.add(intArray[i]);
```

at the end you can get an array from the ArrayList if you want:

```
return myList.toArray();
```